# Vertical align element to bottom

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have several element I want to equalize. For this I'm using a basic function that reads the biggest height and sets it to all those elements.

On each element I have a couple of inner elements. The last one of this inner elements I want to vertical align to the bottom.

```
-------MainElement------
|  _________________   |
| |                 |  |
| | First Elem      |  |
| |_________________|  |
|  _________________   |
| |                 |  |
| | Second Elem     |  |
| |_________________|  |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|  _________________   |
| |       Last      |  |
| | Vertical Bottom |  |
| |_________________|  |
|-----------------------
```

The first element and the second one might have variable height depending on its content (text and image), but the last one will be always fixed

If I try to vertical align the last element **using a position absolute, then this breaks my equalize function** that sets an inline height css property to the element.

```
-------MainElement------
|  _________________   |
| |                 |  |
| | First Elem      |  |
| |_________________|  |
|  _________________   |
| | Second overlaps |  | 
| |_________________|  |
| |       Last      |  |
| | Vertical Bottom |  |
| |_________________|  |
|-----------------------
```

If I try using **display table, and then table-cell to the inner elements this also breaks, since each innerelements shares the total available width** as if they were all elements of the same row.

```
-------MainElement------
|  _____________         |
| |First|2nd   |         |
| |Ele  |Elem  |         |
| |     |      |         |  
| |     |      |_______  |
| |     |      |Vert   | |
| |     |      |Bottom | |
| |_____|______|_______| |
|-------------------------
```

Due to support for old browsers, **I can't use display flex** which is great actually but doesn't behave nicely with IE =(

If there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're using JS anyway I'd suggest you adapt that to suit your requirements. Flexbox is *designed* for this. If you can't use it...JS is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox: Define the container as a flexcontainer with these settings:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: space-between;
}
```

...and then add `margin-top: auto` to the last child element

Comment: Will edit the question now, due to the need of old browsers support (ie10) I can't use display flex =(